# WooCommerce - Dynamic content description with information about pricing in the chosen currency and variations

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I am using the "WooCommerce Currency Switcher" plugin and would like to use dynamic content as default description for the products.

**Example:**

Get the "{product title}" for {currency symbol}{sale price} instead of {currency symbol}{price}.
The "{product title}" is available in different {attribute 1}s and {attribute 2}s.

**The product description would look like this:**

Get the "Superman T-Shirt" for $ 19.90 instead of $ 39.90.
The "Superman T-Shirt" is available in different colors and sizes.

With the right variables or shortcodes it should display the price in the selected currency and according to the chosen variations.

What's the best way to do that? I don't know much about php :-(